# Html form refuses to be submitted via JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So I was following an AJAX/JQuery tutorial for a registration script that will be acted upon by PHP/MySQL and will be submitted via JQuery.

Now the problem that I'm encountering is that the form submits directly to the action page, which should not be so, as it supposed to submit to **script.js** Here are the html code for the form.

```
<form  method="post" id="register-form" action="transact-user.php">     
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading"></h2>
    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class='row'>
                        <div class='col-sm-6'>
                        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='fname' name='fname' placeholder="First name">
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-sm-6'>
                        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='lname' name='lname' placeholder="Last name">
                        </div>
                        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number"  name = "phone" id = "phone" >
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address"  name = "email" id ="email">
    <span id="check-e"></span>
  </div>

   <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name = "password" id = "password">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password Again" name = "confirmpassword" id = "confirmpassword">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-apply" type="submit" name="btn-save" id = "btn-submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp;Register</button>
   </div>


  </form>

</div> <!-- /container -->

<div id = "ack"></div>
```

**script.js**

```
$("button#btn-submit").click(function()
{  /* validation */

   /* form submit */

       if ($("fname").val()=="" || $("lname").val()=="" )
       $("div#ack").html("Please enter both your first name and your surname");

       else
           $.post($("#register-form").attr("action"),
                    $("#register-form:  input").serializeArray(),
                    function(data){
                     $("div#ack").html(data);   
                    });

           $("#register-form").submit(function(){
               return false;
           })         
   /* form submit */

});
```

Finally, this is the action php script **transact-user.php**

```
    <?php

if($_POST)
{

$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$confirmpassword = $_POST['confirmpassword'];




        if($email != '') {
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$qry);
    if($result) {
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

                        echo "Email already in use";

        }
        @mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
    else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
}
            $activation = md5(uniqid(rand(), true)); 

            if ($stmt = "INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname, email, password, verification, phone)"
                    ." values('$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$password', "
                    . "'$activation','$phone')" or 
                    die("Could not perform query ".mysqli_error($mysqli))) {

            $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $stmt)
                                or die("The system could not register you"
                       . "".mysqli_error($mysqli) . "<br>" . $stmt);    

                if ($result){


                echo "sent";


                }

                //echo "<a href=\"gethotel.php?hid=".$row['hotel_id'].
                //<a href = ""></a>

                /* close statement */
                //$stmt->close();
                }

    }

 ?>
```

Comment: take a look at preventDefault

Comment: Change your register button type from `submit` to `button`

Comment: @ReaganGallant that's a bad idea. It means the form cannot be submit when a user hits return on an appropriate field, and makes the form less accessible for screen readers.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan for screen readers you add the attribute role="button". his form gets posted using the action method and not jquery because his button is set to submit.

Comment: @ReaganGallant changed it, and it works pretty fine. Thanks

Comment: No problem.Glad I could help.

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer as it was helpful. Can you please accept it? http://stackoverflow.com/a/38954690/4609867

Answer (score 0):

The issue us because you are hooking to the `click` event of the `submit` button and are not preventing the event from completing.

Also note that your selector to build the querystring is incorrect, as there should be a space before the `:` and not between the `:` and `input`, eg `$("#register-form :input")`

To fix the issues hook to the `submit` event of the `form` and use `preventDefault()`. Try this:

```
$("#register-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($("fname").val().trim() == "" || $("lname").val().trim() == "") {
        $("div#ack").html("Please enter both your first name and your surname");
    } else {
        $.post(this.action, $(this).find(':input').serializeArray(), function(data) {
            $("div#ack").html(data);   
        });   
    }     
});
```